# browser wont cache image loaded through php proxy

Tags: php, caching

currently using a simple php image proxy to load external images to ensure they don't mess with SSL. The problem is, on my live site they only seem to get stored in the memory cache and not the disk cache, so as soon as you close the tab/browser they get downloaded again.

Here's the code:

```
session_cache_limiter('public');

if (isset($_GET['url']))
{
    header('Cache-control: max-age='.(60*60*24*365));
    header('Expires: '.gmdate(DATE_RFC1123,time()+60*60*24*365));
    header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate(DATE_RFC1123,filemtime($_GET['url'])));

    define("APP_ROOT", dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));
    require APP_ROOT . "/includes/bootstrap.php";

    $url_check = parse_url($_GET['url']);

    if (isset($url_check['scheme']) && ($url_check['scheme'] == 'http' || $url_check['scheme'] == 'https'))
    {
        $image_raw = core::file_get_contents_curl($_GET['url']);

        $new_image = imagecreatefromstring($image_raw);

        if ($new_image !== false) 
        {
            $image_info = getimagesizefromstring($image_raw);
            $image_type = $image_info['mime'];

            if (stripos($image_type, 'image/') !== false)
            {
                header('Content-Type: '.$image_type);
                imagepng($new_image);
                imagedestroy($new_image);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Not a valid image url!';
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this limited to Chrome or does it happen on other browsers as well?

Comment: Happens in firefox too, will remove the chrome tag.

Comment: Are those headers actually output? What's the exact response with headers returned?

Comment: You're right, expires wasn't being set. Changing session_cache_limiter to just nothing '' - fixes that. Still doesn't cache it though, last modified time seems to be Thu, 01 Jan 1970 which may be part of the issue?